# Remove classes of a STL::list<class something> which include a dynamic pointer

Tags: c++, list, stl, delete-operator

I have a question and I can't find an answer anywhere. However, there is some code I have to show:

```
  #include "Vector2D"

    class something
    {
        Vector2D * p_Position;
      public:
        something(){p_Position = new Vector2D;}
        ~something(){delete p_Position;}
    };

    int main()
{
    std::list<something> Somethinglist;

    Somethinglist.push_back(something());

    Somethinglist.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

So, this will lead to an assertion fail when it comes to the `.clear()` function. So I tried out a few things. First of all this code completely works if I just don't put the `delete p_Position` in the deconstructor. Why is that? Does the STL list `.clear()` function automatically destroy dynamic Pointers? Or a rather direct question: How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all this code completly works if i just don't put the delete p_Position in the deconstructor.

Because `p_Position` won't be deallocated if you didn't put it in destructor. it causes memory leak.

> Why is that. Does the STL list .clear() function automaticly destroy dynamic Pointers?

STL container keeps a copy of original object. when `.clear()`, these objects will be freed and their destructors will be called.

> Or a rather direct question: How can i fix this code?

Follow [**Rule of Three**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

OR use **smart pointer**

```
#include <memory>
class something
{
    std::unique_ptr<Vector2D> p_Position;
  public:
    something(){}
    ~something(){}
};
```

OR use it without pointer

```
class something
{
   Vector2D p_Position;
  public:
    something(){}
};
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot guys, the Rule of Three was one way to a solution, it works now !

Answer (score 5):

`std::list::push_back()` takes its argument by value (i.e. a copy is produced), and that's a real problem because you haven't followed the [*Rule of Three*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: I'm always wondering why isn't the language designed so that std containers can hold **references** to the objects added to them. (I understand that as it's currently standing, it's impossible, since dynamic memory management is required **and** we can't have pointers to references, but stil...)

Comment: so basicly, what i am trying to do is not possible?

Comment: @TilmanZuckmantel: Did you read the question/answer I linked to?